# X - unitary complex space, Y - real version of X. Show that Y is unitary. What form does the dot product have?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let X be a complex unitary space and Y its real ($\mathbb{R}$) version. Show that Y is unitary. What is the form of dot product in Y?

---

Well, I'm having issues with even understanding the question. Is there a term like "realification of vector space"?  Does it mean that $Y = Re(X)$? Do I have to define a mapping between them (which naturally would be $U: X \to Y: U(x) = Re(x)$)?

Comment: As sets $Y=X$. If $X$ is a vector space over the field of complex numbers it is also a vector space over the field of real numbers and $Y$ is $X$when viewed as a vector space over the field of real numbers.

Comment: Thank you, I think you made it clear. Why X being unitary over $\mathbb{C}$ implies that  X is also unitary over $\mathbb{R}$? Does the dot product stay the same?